# If A is an m by n matrix, prove that the set of vectors b that are not in C(A) forms a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If **A** is an m by n matrix, prove that the set of vectors **b** that are not in **C(A)**  forms a subspace.

I would like to first understand if I am interpreting the question correctly. My understanding of this question is that I need to first prove that the set of vectors **b** are equal to the 0 vector, and if b1 and b2 are members of the subspace, then the sum of set **b** should be a member, and so should some scalar **C** multiplied by the set of vectors **b**.  I just don't understand how to actually prove this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is wrong. Maybe this picture can help you figure out.

[image]

Since every subspace must contain the zero vector, noted by $\underline{0}$.

We know that $C(A)$ is a subspace for $\mathbb{R}^m$, so $\underline{0}\in C(A) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$, that means the zero vector are inside the column space and also $\mathbb{R}^m$.

But if we consider $\mathbb{R}^m\setminus C(A)$, by the picture, it means we are now cancelling the red circle out, so the zero vector is no longer inside this "space".

Therefore, it can not form a subspace.

Answer (score 5):

Your first condition should be $0$ is in a subspace.

Also, the result is not true.

Let $0_m$ be the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$. We know that $0_m \in C(A)$ since $\sum_{i=1}^n A_i \cdot 0=0_m$.

$0_m$ is in $C(A)$, $0_m$ can't be in the set of vector that are not in $C(A)$. Hence the set of vectors that are not in $C(A)$ can't form a subspace.

Comment: How do I know that 0 is in C(A)?

Comment: $C(A)$ is the column space right?

Comment: Correct. I am new to linear algebra and am trying to understand the definitions Column space, null space, subspace, etc...Perhaps I am not understanding the proper definition of column space

Comment: I have included an explaination of why $0_m \in C(A)$.